# Dynamics - trigger check for required fields without saving

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm searching for a way to show the standard error message that show next to the required fields when a form is saved, but without actually saving it.

Comment: did it solved your question?

Answer (score 1):

Validation will happen on save if they are required fields. You may trigger the save event in form load like this:

```
formContext.data.entity.save(saveOption);
```

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/formcontext-data-entity/save)

But still you can add notification to fields on change or on form load for custom scenarios.

```
Xrm.Page.getControl(arg).setNotification(message,uniqueId)
```

[Read more](http://himbap.com/blog/?p=2634)

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are on latest online version of Dynamics, I would recommend you user [addnotification with execution context.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/controls/addnotification)

Here is the code you need, need to customize as per your need, Example show notification type as recommended but you can use Error so that form does not save and display error as well.

```
function addTickerSymbolRecommendation(executionContext) {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    var myControl = formContext.getControl('name');
    var accountName = formContext.data.entity.attributes.get('name');
    var tickerSymbol = formContext.data.entity.attributes.get('tickersymbol');

    if (accountName.getValue() == 'Microsoft' && tickerSymbol.getValue() != 'MSFT') {
        var actionCollection = {
            message: 'Set the Ticker Symbol to MSFT?',
            actions: null
        };

        actionCollection.actions = [function () {
            tickerSymbol.setValue('MSFT');
            myControl.clearNotification('my_unique_id');
        }];

        myControl.addNotification({
            messages: ['Set Ticker Symbol'],
            notificationLevel: 'RECOMMENDATION',
            uniqueId: 'my_unique_id',
            actions: [actionCollection]
        });
    }
    else
        console.log("Notification not set");
}
```